# Modify Angular component selector with variable

Tags: angular, components

My idea is to modify component selector string with variable so that I could dynamically select template to display.

Unfortunately using simple `"<app-{{selectedComponent}}></app-{{selectedComponent}}>"` inside `*ngFor` loop do not work.
Is there any way to dynamically select component to display?

Comment: That's a brilliant question. Will definitely work on this and get back with an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should use structural directive `*ngIf` to display some element/component dynamically inside your `.html` file.

An example would be:
`<app-xyz-component *ngIf='someCase'><app-xyz-component>`

If the expression is `true` component will be rendered.

Comment: In such case I would have to write as many such lines as many components I have to choose from. My idea is to write one line which would have dynamic component selector.

Comment: Tbh, I think the most you can get is a `ngSwitch` directive. At least is more elegant then `*ngIf` https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it's not possible but you can use `ngSwitch` or `ngIf` or if you want to dynamically create components on the fly you can use Dynamic component loader follow this [link](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader) Or [this link](https://netbasal.com/dynamically-creating-components-with-angular-a7346f4a982d)